# query to get user info using Ajax

Tags: visualforce

***emphasized text***

```
<apex:page >
<script>
var result = sforce.connection.query("Select Name,Id from User", {
onSuccess : success, onFailure : failure});
function success(result) {
var it = new sforce.QueryResultIterator(result);
while(it.hasNext()){
var record = it.next();
log(record.Name + " -- " + record.Id);
}
}
function failure(error) {
log("An error has occurred " + error);
}

</script>
  <apex:form >
  <apex:pageBlock >
  <apex:commandButton value="get user info" onclick="chechDevMode();"/>
  </apex:pageBlock>
  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

this is my vf page,,am trying to get user info,by clcking the button get user info,,pls suggest how to do it.thanks in advance.

Comment: do you want to get current user details ? if yes no need use soql. you can use visualforce global variable $user ....... https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_global_user.htm

Comment: using Ajax i hav to get the user info

Comment: try like this `"Select Name,Id from User WHERE Id = '{!$user.Id}' "`

Comment: not working sir

Comment: what is not working.. are you using above same code.. I can't see you are using connection.js in your page

Comment: <script src="../../soap/ajax/37.0/connection.js"
          type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: Sahi check my answer and let me know if you got current user name and Id in browser console or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code..

You need to add connection.js else you will get error like sforce is not define..

or you can use $user global variable to get the current user info..

Since you need an example to get the sforce.query result

Example

```
<apex:page >
    <script src="../../soap/ajax/37.0/connection.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script>
    sforce.connection.sessionId='{!$Api.Session_ID}';
    var result = sforce.connection.query("Select Name,Id from User WHERE Id = '{!$User.Id}'", {
    onSuccess : success, onFailure : failure});
    function success(result) {
        var it = new sforce.QueryResultIterator(result);
        while(it.hasNext()){
        var record = it.next();
        console.log(record.Name + " -- " + record.Id);
        }
    }
    function failure(error) {
        console.log("An error has occurred " + error);
    }

    </script>
  <apex:form >
      <apex:pageBlock >
        <apex:commandButton value="get user info" onclick="chechDevMode();"/>
      </apex:pageBlock>
  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

---

one more simple solution
that I like most using `$user` global variable

```
<apex:page>
<apex:form >
      <apex:pageBlock >
        <apex:commandButton value="get user info" onclick="chechDevMode();"/><br/>

        <h1 >{!$User.FirstName} {!$User.LastName}</h1> <br/>
        <h1 >{!$User.Id}</h1>
      </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: I did copy paste yur code,iam not getting whether the info is getting or not,,can u please tel how to bind the result in the same page

Comment: @sahisfdc use javascript bind the value into element

Comment: in the {!result} format

Comment: @sahisfdc I didn't get you.. what is this `{!result}` ?

Comment: am not getting how to bind user info

Comment: can u please tel me vat to do

Comment: @sahisfdc first make me understand your requirement then i could help you more. I am not getting what you are trying to do.. and what you need if both clear then I could help you more. can you add some more info in your question so i can understand

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41792/discussion-between-ratan-and-sahisfdc).

Comment: i understood my requirement,iam not getting whether result var catching the data r not.

Comment: @sahisfdc join this chat room http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41792/discussion-between-ratan-and-sahisfdc